# Not able to create record using a newly created profile in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I created a user testaccount1 in the `active directory`, and then created a new user profile in the CRM 2016 and added the account to a security group

I was able to create records that I have given access for that account

I repeated the same steps and created a testaccount2 in `active directory`, created a user profile in CRM and added to the same security group as testaccoutn1

But when I try to create record using the testaccount2 I get the below error

> Insufficient Permissions You do not have permission to access these
>   records. Contact your Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrator.

There is only one security role that is assigned to both these accounts, where should I look for to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit **Download log file**

> - **the error message will give you the specific permission that    is missing**

(it will look something like "**prvContactCreate" if you are lacking create on the contact record at the level of scope/depth required).  Once you post the error message here, we will be able to give more detailed responses.  Question - When creating the record with the second account - are you by chance setting the owner as someone other than yourself?  If so, what is the depth of the privilege for the security role on the given user?

Comment: Thanks @joseph upvoted
the solution was strange, i added the user to administrator security role, refreshed the page, and then removed the user from administrator role and refreshed the page and it worked!!
I did so because, i remember adding and remvoing the testuser1 to administrator role